# Beginner N-channel MOSFET question. Is there a benefit to connecting or floating extra pins?

Tags: mosfet, pcb

On an N-channel MOSFET [(SI4848,)](https://www.vishay.com/docs/71356/si4848dy.pdf) is there any benefit or downside to connecting all relative pins together, like in the image, connect all drain together, all source together, etc.?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there are benefits. Whether you need to connect all of them for your specific application, no one excepted you can know (at least if you don't explain what you mean to do with this MOSFET).

What comes to mind right now :

- lower resistance in the pins. Your MOSFET has a quite low Rdson (ie low "on" resistance) : <100 mohms. It's low enough the resistance of individual pins (ie the metal part + solder joints) might start to matter
- lower thermal resistance to the rest of the PCB (it's easier to transfer heat through 8 pins than through 3)
- better mechanical resistance (ie better resistance to vibrations, shocks, ...)

Comment: Thank you very much. I decided to do a polygon pour for the area to dissipate heat as well.

Answer (score 5):

> *is there any benefit or negative to connecting all relative pins
> together*

Absolutely. You **must** always do this unless you have some unimaginable compelling reason not to do so. Each pin draws heat away from the silicon die and keeps the MOSFET cooler. Pins in parallel offer a lower activated on-resistance too.

Answer (score 1):

It is a benefit if your using the Mosfet close to its maximum current, and/or using it at high frequencies, such as a switch-mode supply or ultrasound or RF. If it is just to light an LED or switch small relay then you can let extra leads float.

Comment: ...but if it's just to light an LED or switch a small relay, you've probably got the wrong FET for the job and can replace it with a much cheaper one.

Comment: @Hearth Agreed. Any 2N2222 can light an LED.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they should be connected together. Electrically, it doesn't matter - you only need one pin of each terminal of the transistor. However, if and when you create a PCB, those extra pins help considerably in getting heat out of the package. Plus, you would have those pins soldered to pads anyway, so you're getting the mechanical advantages for free.

Comment: They also help getting current out of the package